# Converting useEffect function to componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem in which some files are using new `useEffect` and some are using the older `componentDidMount`, I am more familiar with `useEffect` and I have the following async function below:

```
 const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
 useEffect(() => {
     const fetchUser = async () => {
         const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
         getUserData(user.username).then((user) => {
             setUser(user);
         });
     };
     fetchUser();
 }, []);
```

The above function is what I am trying to replicate below:

```
this.state = {
    user: null,
};

async fetchUser() {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const res = await getUserData(user.username);
        this.setState({ user: res });
        console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error, 'Error: cant retrieve user data');
    }
}

async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchUser();
}
```

However, I cannot retrieve the same outcome with the `componentDidMount` function, how could I do this?

Comment: what's wrong with it? it seems correct to me.

Comment: @skyboyer yes, im not sure, when logging out user i dont get the same object

Comment: In the functional component, you are using `useContext` but in the class component, you use normal `state`. Does the Context changes something or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Paul, as indicated in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), `useEffect` is equivalent to `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined, so your new code is missing the latter methods to be equivalent to the old code.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi okay, ill try and attempt that thankyou